# How do I use FZF's keybinding in ZSH's vi mode?

Tags: zsh, vim, fzf

After applying the command: `set -o vi` in ZSH, I can't get FZF keybinding works as before, ex `^CR` for reverse history search.. How can I make this works again?

Answer (score 1):

First set your keymap, *then* source Fzf's shell script. Otherwise, Fzf's shell script will install all the keybindings into the default `emacs` keymap (after which you then switch to `vi`).

Answer (score 0):

I used this Plugin as my base. https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode
Its just a better vi-mode for zsh.

Then I inserted the Keymap of fzf into the file zsh-vi-mode.zsh of the Plugin under the "#Other key bindings" Comment. I had to change the Keybinding command of the fzf-keymap from `bindkey'<key>' <funktion>` to `zvm_bindkey viins '<key>' <fzf-funktion>`.

Depending, where you insert the fzf-keymap, you have to uncomment the line `zvm_bindkey viins '^R' history-incremental-search-backward`

One word to the keymap of fzf. Depending how you installed fzf, you will find it under the installation directory or under /usr/share/fzf.

Then I loaded first the fzf plugin and second the zsh-vi-mode plugin. The second one should overwrite the first.

There could be a better way doing this but it works for me. I hope I was able to help.

Comment: i forgot. 
you need to be in insertmode to use the fzf keybindings.